# Brightness automatically getting changed

Tags: kali-linux, xrandr, brightness

I am using ‘xrandr —output  —brightness 0.7’ in Kali Linux to control brightness and its working cool but sometimes brightness is getting changed automatically and I am stuck here. Same happening in my friends laptop too.

Comment: I use `brightnessctl` without problems, you could try it. `sudo apt install brightnessctl` to install, `brightnessctl g` to get the current brightness, `brightnessctl s [integer]` to set it. I've also added `acpi_backlight=vendor` to kernel parametres; it was needed to restore brightness level to previous level, after screen was turned off, due to power saving. Else it was restored to default level.

Comment: Thanks for you help I will try brightnessctl. However even when i am using the laptop also suddenly brightness increasing automatically( Power saving is turned off).

Comment: In that case, probably `acpi_backlight=` parametres may help you more. Check https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Backlight regardless of your distro; it's very helpful.

Comment: @Krackout I don't want to touch any kernal commands here. Can you please tell me any other way?

Comment: Sorry, that's all I've used for brightness control on laptops.